# Users representing groupings in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I'm looking at creating activity streams to represent the activity of a museum collection. In this case the actors are the artists & makers of the museums' objects, and (ideally) their streams they can be followed, to see what is happening with the collection. However I'm not sure if this maps across very well to the user model, as I assume that's really intended for real life users. Is there some other way to map this grouping into the activity streams format, to create an activity stream something like:

John Constable feed:
1 Jan 2019:  Painting 'The Hay Wain' has been moved to Gallery 20.

(I'm assuming here 'moved' is the verb, Gallery is the object, and 'The Hay Wain' is a collection)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible solutions to this are:

- use a collection entry as the actor for these activities, for instance an artist collection with all the artist.
- use a user as the actor, but make sure that the user ID of artist is different than your real life users. For instance by prefixing it with `artist-`.